# Changed main.cpp to main.c and stopped building with CMake on Clion

Tags: c++, c, gcc, cmake

My CMake file contains the following

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(MyProject)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -pthread")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.c vector.h aLib.h vector.c)
add_executable(MyProject ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

As soon as I changed the `main.cpp` to `main.c` I received an error

> /home/MyProject/main.c:203: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
>   /home/MyProject/main.c:210: undefined reference to`pthread_join'

It used to work while it was `.cpp`. In terminal if I run `gcc -pthread main.c vector.c` it compilers without issues. There must be some CMake command wrong but I'm not very familiar with it. Also I guess I need to remove the `-std=c++11` ?

Comment: I wonder what happens if you rename the file to `.java` or `.py`. What do you expect compiling one language as different one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the file's extension "main.cpp" to "main.c" signals your compiler that it is not dealing with a C++ file, but a C file.

Compiling C is different than compiling C++, so you will need to alter your build rules to match, probably you will also have to rewrite the code inside the file to adhere to C standards (C++ standards are different), and you will likely have a very difficult time linking your C launcher to other C++ items, so you might have to find alternatives (or rewrite them if you have their source code).

You can't just change a file's name and expect this work to be done automatically.  It is the equivalent of changing a 'myfile.docx' to a 'myfile.pdf' and thinking the internals of the file will rewrite itself form a Micosoft Word Document to a PDF.

Comment: Ok, It compiles with gcc so there is no problem here. What are the CMake rules that I need to change?

Comment: I would start by setting C_FLAGS instead of CXX_FLAGS.  Your CMake rules lack any indication what C compiler Flags are required.

Comment: Removing the XX did the job. This rules are the default. Should I be aware of others that affect my project?

Comment: Generally speaking, directives that use CXX in their name come from the standards that pre-existed CMake in the GNU Make Makefiles.  They are almost always the C++ equivalent of a previously existing C directive, so I would scan your CMake files for CXX directives and then research if it makes sense to drop the "XX" part.  I don't know for sure, but I suspect they chose "XX" instead of "++" because the latter is an operator in Makefiles

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the .c extension but still compile with a C++ compiler instead of a C compiler, you can also use something like:

```
set_source_files_properties(main.c 
  PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX)
```